# Simultaneous logins to same account in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

There's posts on preventing simultaneous logins from multiple machines, but I actually want to do the opposite and allow simultaneous logins to the same account from multiple machines. Is there a limit to the number of simultaneous logins ? I have tested it wth 2 logins but I want to allow up to a 100 or more. Thanks.

Comment: Which authentication system are you using ? If that's one of your own, then you're the one setting up the limits.

Comment: using forms authentication with username/password

Comment: If you didn't set any limit, there's no limit. But allowing 100+ concurrent logins of the same account can't reasonably be called "authentication". A somehow weak access control it is.

Comment: ASP.NET is stateless (except the Session object). You authenticate with each request and you are 'logged out' for each response (except for that cookie). You can do this from as many machines as you like until your server falls over from load. The hard thing is to impose a stateful mental model over asp.net and get it to act as if it were a stateful framework (with a logon at 8AM and logoff at 5PM)

Comment: Yea i agree, but that is what the customer wants. thanks for the help.

Comment: I think what you want is load testing. As far as authentication, only machines can log on to 100 different machines at the same time. I can at best log on to 2 or 3 machines at the same time.

Comment: the customer requirement i have is to give the same account credentials to 100 of more people